# Is there a way to get HTML data from an active browser (Python)

Tags: python, html, bots

I'm just messing around with python automation and attempting  to create a Cookie Clicker bot.

I was wondering if you can get HTML data (e.g ID's Names, etc) from an already open browser, 
and use them into locating where to click, if you should click, etc. Don't know if it's a dumb question, but I'm a beginner so help would be appreciated.

*I have tried selenium, but the point is to be able to control my main chrome browser

Comment: search for "python webdriver", I think it's the way to do that (selenium and other tools)

Comment: not easily...its much easier to use selenium to open a new browser and navigate around ... I dont think it can be bound to an already open webbrowser though (i could be wrong)

Comment: maybe better write browser extension with JavaScript. Eventually extension could send HTML to your web server created with Python.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out stuff like Selenium and robotic process automation for that. Try this: https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/

Comment: I know selenium, but I want to be able to control my own browser, not create a new one. Point is to be able to control Cookie Clicker through my main chrome.

Comment: I would think that it would make more sense to make a js chrome plugin for that